# Not receiving mail sent by php even though I get "successfully submitted message"

Tags: php, html, email

i try to send email through  html form\php codes i get the `successfully submitted message` when i check my email inbox i have not received any message even i check my spam too no message yet received to my mail ? this is my php code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="8;URL=form.html"> 
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
  <?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mailto = "xyz@gmail.com";
$mailsubj = "Form submission";
$mailhead = "From: $email\n";
$mailbody = "Email form the web site form:\n";
echo $_POST['email'];
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($_POST)) { $mailbody.= "$key : $val\n"; }
if (!eregi("\n",$_POST['email'])) {mail($mailto, $mailsubj, $mailbody, $mailhead);}
//print_r($HTTP_POST_VARS);
//header('Location:http://74.52.47.117/~irtech/irtech/');

?>
  <span class="bodyw style1" >Thanks for enquiry we will contact you soon.</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your php.ini you should setup your smtp server. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which email client / program you are using, you will need to add a doctype and html tags to the body of the email, and declare the Content-type in your headers.

Try to change your `$mailbody` and `$mailhead` as following:

```
$mailbody = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><body>
<p>Email form the web site form:</p>
</body></html>';

$mailhead = "From: $email\n";
$mailhead .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

It's also worth noting, that if you are sending an html mail, you just need to use `<p>` and `<br>`, it won't recognize `\n`.